# How to properly add column to the Excel table and insert a formula using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to be able to add column and insert formula thats looks up for values from a pivot table. 'Peer Group Name' is one of the table column. So far, I'm doing this:

```
Set wrk = ThisWorkbook
Set trg_sht = wrk.Worksheets("Peers & Instruments - Overview")
Set tbl = trg_sht.ListObjects("Peers_Instruments_Values")

' Add few additional columns on position 26 & 27
tbl.ListColumns.Add(26).Name = "Median 1Y Return"
tbl.ListColumns.Add(27).Name = "Max 1Y Return"

tbl.ListColumns("Median 1Y Return").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([@[Peer Group Name]]," & "'" & CStr(wrk.Worksheets("Peer Group Stats") & "'" & "!C[-25]:C[-22],3,0)")
```

So the two columns are being added, but the formula doesn't. Any idea why? Is it something do to with wrong column reference?

Comment: What happens? Do you get a runtime error? Or an empty column? You have `On Error Resume Next` in your code? Try a simpler formula (I tried `=RC[-1]+RC[-2]` and that worked).

Comment: @FunThomas yes, the column is empty. No errors. Your formula works! But how to adjust it so I could operate on actual table column along with a reference to a pivot?

Comment: `CStr(wrk.Worksheets("Peer Group Stats")` looks off. You just need a string with that worksheet's name.

Comment: You could try the other way around: Write the formula into a cell of the column, go to the VBA and type `? ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` to get an idea how it should look like

Comment: ah, ok. Got it. So I actually don't have to reference a spreadsheet, just its name. I can already see something pops up, so I'm heading into good direction looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks off:

```
CStr(wrk.Worksheets("Peer Group Stats") & "'" & "!C[-25]:C[-22],3,0)")
```

You don't need a reference to the worksheet, nor `CStr`. You just need the worksheet name, which can be hard-coded:

```
tbl.ListColumns("Median 1Y Return").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([@[Peer Group Name]],'Peer Group Stats'!C[-25]:C[-22],3,0)"
```

Comment: Good catch - however I wonder why the OP didn't get a runtime error

Comment: I suspect there's an `On Error Resume Next` we don't know about.

Comment: That's why I asked in the comments...

Comment: Yeah, and OP just mentioned "no errors", but did not actually answer your question on `On Error Resume Next`...

Comment: I'm sorry, the code actually had 'On Error Resume Next' statement.